# Ansible cannot reach localhost

Tags: ssh, ansible, devops

I created keys with command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa

chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then i used command
`ssh-copy-id timur@127.0.0.1`

Now command
`ssh 127.0.0.1`
doesn't require password.
Then i created hosts file for ansible

```
[staging_servers]

linux_local ansible_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=timur ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/timur/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When i run `ansible all -m ping` i'm getting error:

[![error picture][1]][1]

What i did wrong?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMKt0.png

Answer (score 2):

`.ssh/authorized_keys` is not a private key file, it holds public keys that have been authorized. You also do not appear to have changed the permissions on the actual private key file to be acceptable to openssh.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to change something on localhost, there is a better option: use `connection: local` in the playbook, or use this inventory:

```
[staging_servers]
linux_local ansible_connection=local
```

It will completely skip whole ssh thing and run modules directly on the local machine.

Moreover, from my experience, it's the fastest way to run Ansible. If you can afford to mess with local machine, do it, it's a bliss to work with.